# On Hover of Department menu getting flickered i want to create drop-down menu

Tags: html, css

On Hover of Department menu getting flickered i want to create drop-down menu Please help! 
im working on website design and i want to create a dropdown menu below the title 
this is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" >
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 
           <div class="main">
           
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo1"><img src="logo1.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
                    <div class="text1"><strong>AGNIHOTRI COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING,<br>WARDHA</strong>
        <br><div style="float:left;text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:brown;padding-left:50px">(Near Bypass Highway,Nagthana Road Sindi(Meghe))<br>Email:ace@agnihotri.org
        <br>Phone:07152-250152
        </div> </div>
                    <div class="logo2"><img src="12.png" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="navbar">
         <ul>
      <li><a href="#">AGI</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Governance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Campus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Basic Science</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Machanical Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Civil Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Computer science & Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Electronics & Communication Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(computer science & Engg.)</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(Electronics)</a></li>
                     </ul> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Addmission</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Facility</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallary</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     
            <div class="middle">
               <div class="mid-wrapper">
                <img src="3.jpg" width="934px" height="250px">
                     </div>
 
            </div>
      <div class="web">
           <div class="section">
             <div class="section-left" style="padding-left:10px">
               <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>News</b></h2>
                 <p style="color:black;text-align:center"><marquee direction="up"><b>ALL THE BEST STUDENTS <br>FOR UNIVERSITY EXAM:<b></p><br>
                 <p style="color:blue;text-align:center">University Summer 2018<br> Exam Timetables<br> Are Available In<br> The Download Section: </marquee></p>
   
           <div class="video">
                 <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>Video</b></h2>
           <video controls autoplay width="200px" height="100px" >
           <source src="college.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           </video>
                             <br></div> 
                            <div class="image" style="padding-left:10px">
                 <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>Image</b></h2>
           <img src="img1.jpg" alt="" width="170px" height="90px">
                             <br></div>       
          </div>
             <div class="section-right">
                        <h2 style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:500px;height:30px;text-align:center">Welcome to <span>Agnihotri College Of Engineering</span></h2>
             
                  <p style="color:blue;font-size:14px">Agnihotri College Of Engineering Nagthana Road is a Affiliated college institution.... We represnt the same Fact in user-friendly way<br> </p>
               <hr>
      <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Vision</div>
      <p></p><br><br>
      <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Misson</div>
      <p></p><br><br>
                       <hr>
      </div>
     <div class="mid"> 
          <div class="bottam-right">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white">President's Message</h2>
                              <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285">
                         <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float: left; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
            <br><b>I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
                               <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
                         </div>
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white">Scretory"s Message</span></h2>
            <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285px">
         <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float:left; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
              <br><b> I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing   unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
           <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
         </div>
          <div class="">
                             <br><br><br>
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white;padding-top:10px">Principle's Message</h2>
                              <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285">
                        <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float: left; margin-top:5px;"></div>
             <br><b>I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
                               <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
     </div> 
       </div>
           
        </div>
 

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and this is css:

on hover menu of department i want dropdown menus

```css
body{background-color:black}

.main{ margin:0 auto; padding:0px;background-color:white;font-family:Arial,Helentica;font-size:12px; color:#000;width:814px;background-color:white}

.header{width:814px;height:123px;padding:65px 0px 0px 120px;font-size:12px; color:black;font-family:Arial;background-color:white}

.logo1{float:left;padding-right:50px;}

.logo2{float:right;padding-right:50px}

.text1{float:left;text-align:center;font-size:20px;color:brown}

.navbar{float:left;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:gray;height:30px;position:absolute;width:934px}

.navbar ul{ display:inline; list-style:none;}

.navbar li{float:left;text-align:center;font:normal bold 12px/2.5em Arial,verdana;text-decoration:none;}

.navbar ul li a{ padding:0 40px 0 20px; border-left:1px solid black;text-decoration:none;color:white;display:block-line;height:50px;}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color:black;}

.navbar li ul  {display: none; height: auto;margin: 0;padding:0}
                
.navbar li:hover ul {display: block}
                        
.navbar li ul li {background-color:gray;border:1px solid black}
    
.navbar li ul li a:hover{background-color:black;}

.mid-wrapper{padding:39px 0px}

.section-left{float:left}

.section-right{float:right}

.news{margin:0px;padding: 20px; width: 256px; float: left;display: block;}

.section-left{background:white;font-weight:none;float:left;}

.section-left li{list-style:none;padding-left:10px;}

.video{ background:white; color:white;padding-left:10px;}

.section-right{background-color:white;font-weight:none;padding-left:10px; width:576px;}

.bottam-right{width:286px;float:left;padding-left:10px;background:white;height:auto;}

.bottam-left{padding-left:37px; background-color:white;width:50px}

.bottam-middle li{list-style:none;padding-left:10px;}

 .section-right p{padding:0 0 0 20px }
```

i tried but menu drop-down getting flickered please help!

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please validate the HTML https://validator.w3.org/. There are some closing tags missing. And after that, put CSS and HTML in **one** stack snippet together.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main{ margin:0 auto; padding:0px;background-color:white;font-family:Arial,Helentica;font-size:12px; color:#000;width:814px;background-color:white}

.header{width:814px;height:123px;padding:65px 0px 0px 120px;font-size:12px; color:black;font-family:Arial;background-color:white}

.logo1{float:left;padding-right:50px;}

.logo2{float:right;padding-right:50px}

.text1{float:left;text-align:center;font-size:20px;color:brown}

.navbar{float:left;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:gray;height:30px;position:absolute;width:934px}

.navbar ul{ display:inline; list-style:none;    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}

.navbar li{float:left;text-align:center;font:normal bold 12px/2.5em Arial,verdana;text-decoration:none; position:relative}

.navbar ul li a{ padding:0 40px 0 20px; border-left:1px solid black;text-decoration:none;color:white;display:block-line;height:50px;}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color:black;}

.navbar li ul  {display: none; height: auto;margin: 0;padding:0; position:absolute; left:0; top:30px}
                
.navbar li:hover ul {display: block}
                        
.navbar li ul li {background-color:gray;border-bottom:1px solid black; float:none}

.navbar li ul li a { display:block; text-align:left; 
     height: auto; padding:5px 10px;
    border: none;
    width: 220px;}
.navbar li ul li a:hover{background-color:black;}

.mid-wrapper{padding:39px 0px}

.section-left{float:left}

.section-right{float:right}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
           
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo1"><img src="logo1.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
                    <div class="text1"><strong>AGNIHOTRI COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING,<br>WARDHA</strong>
        <br><div style="float:left;text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:brown;padding-left:50px">(Near Bypass Highway,Nagthana Road Sindi(Meghe))<br>Email:ace@agnihotri.org
        <br>Phone:07152-250152
        </div> </div>
                    <div class="logo2"><img src="12.png" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="navbar">
         <ul>
      <li><a href="#">AGI</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Governance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Campus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Basic Science</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Machanical Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Civil Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Computer science & Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Electronics & Communication Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(computer science & Engg.)</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(Electronics)</a></li>
                     </ul> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Addmission</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Facility</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallary</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     
            <div class="middle">
               <div class="mid-wrapper">
                <img src="3.jpg" width="934px" height="250px">
                     </div>
 
            </div>
      <div class="web">
           <div class="section">
             <div class="section-left" style="padding-left:10px">
               <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>News</b></h2>
                 <p style="color:black;text-align:center"><marquee direction="up"><b>ALL THE BEST STUDENTS <br>FOR UNIVERSITY EXAM:<b></p><br>
                 <p style="color:blue;text-align:center">University Summer 2018<br> Exam Timetables<br> Are Available In<br> The Download Section: </marquee></p>
   
           <div class="video">
                 <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>Video</b></h2>
           <video controls autoplay width="200px" height="100px" >
           <source src="college.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           </video>
                             <br></div> 
                            <div class="image" style="padding-left:10px">
                 <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>Image</b></h2>
           <img src="img1.jpg" alt="" width="170px" height="90px">
                             <br></div>       
          </div>
             <div class="section-right">
                        <h2 style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:500px;height:30px;text-align:center">Welcome to <span>Agnihotri College Of Engineering</span></h2>
             
                  <p style="color:blue;font-size:14px">Agnihotri College Of Engineering Nagthana Road is a Affiliated college institution.... We represnt the same Fact in user-friendly way<br> </p>
               <hr>
      <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Vision</div>
      <p></p><br><br>
      <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Misson</div>
      <p></p><br><br>
                       <hr>
      </div>
     <div class="mid"> 
          <div class="bottam-right">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white">President's Message</h2>
                              <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285">
                         <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float: left; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
            <br><b>I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
                               <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
                         </div>
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white">Scretory"s Message</span></h2>
            <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285px">
         <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float:left; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
              <br><b> I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing   unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
           <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
         </div>
          <div class="">
                             <br><br><br>
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white;padding-top:10px">Principle's Message</h2>
                              <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285">
                        <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float: left; margin-top:5px;"></div>
             <br><b>I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
                               <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
     </div> 
       </div>
           
        </div>
 

 </div>
```

Hope this is going to work for you, but make sure your HTML is well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I have just added `.navbar li ul{position:absolute;width:100%;left:0}` in the styles:

```css
body{background-color:black}
.main{ margin:0 auto; padding:0px;background-color:white;font-family:Arial,Helentica;font-size:12px; color:#000;width:814px;background-color:white}

.header{width:814px;height:123px;padding:65px 0px 0px 120px;font-size:12px; color:black;font-family:Arial;background-color:white}

.logo1{float:left;padding-right:50px;}

.logo2{float:right;padding-right:50px}

.text1{float:left;text-align:center;font-size:20px;color:brown}

.navbar{float:left;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:gray;height:30px;position:absolute;width:934px}

.navbar ul{ display:inline; list-style:none;}

.navbar li{float:left;text-align:center;font:normal bold 12px/2.5em Arial,verdana;text-decoration:none;}

.navbar ul li a{ padding:0 40px 0 20px;text-decoration:none;color:white;display:block-line;height:50px;width : 100%}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color:black;}

.navbar li ul  {display: none; height: auto;margin: 0;padding:0;}
.navbar li ul{position:absolute;display : none;width:200px}           
.navbar li:hover ul {display: block}
                        
.navbar li ul li {background-color:gray;border:1px solid black;display:block;width:100%;text-align:left}
    
.navbar li ul li a:hover{background-color:black;}

.mid-wrapper{padding:39px 0px}

.section-left{float:left}

.section-right{float:right}

.news{margin:0px;padding: 20px; width: 256px; float: left;display: block;}

.section-left{background:white;font-weight:none;float:left;}

.section-left li{list-style:none;padding-left:10px;}

.video{ background:white; color:white;padding-left:10px;}

.section-right{background-color:white;font-weight:none;padding-left:10px; width:576px;}

.bottam-right{width:286px;float:left;padding-left:10px;background:white;height:auto;}

.bottam-left{padding-left:37px; background-color:white;width:50px}

.bottam-middle li{list-style:none;padding-left:10px;}

 .section-right p{padding:0 0 0 20px }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" >
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 
           <div class="main">
           
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo1"><img src="logo1.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
                    <div class="text1"><strong>AGNIHOTRI COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING,<br>WARDHA</strong>
        <br><div style="float:left;text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:brown;padding-left:50px">(Near Bypass Highway,Nagthana Road Sindi(Meghe))<br>Email:ace@agnihotri.org
        <br>Phone:07152-250152
        </div> </div>
                    <div class="logo2"><img src="12.png" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="navbar">
         <ul>
      <li><a href="#">AGI</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Governance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Campus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Basic Science</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Machanical Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Civil Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Computer science & Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Electronics & Communication Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(computer science & Engg.)</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(Electronics)</a></li>
                     </ul> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Addmission</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Facility</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallary</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     
            <div class="middle">
               <div class="mid-wrapper">
                <img src="3.jpg" width="934px" height="250px">
                     </div>
 
            </div>
      <div class="web">
           <div class="section">
             <div class="section-left" style="padding-left:10px">
               <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>News</b></h2>
                 <p style="color:black;text-align:center"><marquee direction="up"><b>ALL THE BEST STUDENTS <br>FOR UNIVERSITY EXAM:<b></p><br>
                 <p style="color:blue;text-align:center">University Summer 2018<br> Exam Timetables<br> Are Available In<br> The Download Section: </marquee></p>
   
           <div class="video">
                 <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>Video</b></h2>
           <video controls autoplay width="200px" height="100px" >
           <source src="college.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           </video>
                             <br></div> 
                            <div class="image" style="padding-left:10px">
                 <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white"><b>Image</b></h2>
           <img src="img1.jpg" alt="" width="170px" height="90px">
                             <br></div>       
          </div>
             <div class="section-right">
                        <h2 style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:500px;height:30px;text-align:center">Welcome to <span>Agnihotri College Of Engineering</span></h2>
             
                  <p style="color:blue;font-size:14px">Agnihotri College Of Engineering Nagthana Road is a Affiliated college institution.... We represnt the same Fact in user-friendly way<br> </p>
               <hr>
      <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Vision</div>
      <p></p><br><br>
      <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Misson</div>
      <p></p><br><br>
                       <hr>
      </div>
     <div class="mid"> 
          <div class="bottam-right">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white">President's Message</h2>
                              <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285">
                         <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float: left; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
            <br><b>I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
                               <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
                         </div>
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white">Scretory"s Message</span></h2>
            <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285px">
         <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float:left; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
              <br><b> I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing   unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
           <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
         </div>
          <div class="">
                             <br><br><br>
            <h2 style="text-align:center;background-color:brown;color:white;padding-top:10px">Principle's Message</h2>
                              <img src="" alt="" height="3" width="285">
                        <div style="border-right: 1px solid white; width: 289px; float: left; margin-top:5px;"></div>
             <br><b>I Feel proud and happy</b>to introduce to you ACE and welcome to this prestigious institution,ACE is a managing unprecdented growth through prolifaration of a varity of knowlegeas part
                               <br><a href="#" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
     </div> 
       </div>
           
        </div>
 

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks sir it works  but my need is! horizontal drop-down menu

Comment: Do you mean vertical? Currently, the menu is horizontal

Comment: sorry vertical drop-down menu

Comment: @akshadaRohokale I have changed the menu to a vertical one . Do check